# nave bar how can i do personnalize it?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code I tried to make nav bars with. I have troubles to get `familylink` at the left then the `population` in the middle and the `contact` in the right. I tried to add and remove padding but I cannot find a way.

```css
.buttons {
  background-color: #0d3c4b;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  padding-left: 674px;
  padding-right: 467px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <div class="navebar">
    <ul class="buttons">
      <li style="display:inline-block;" classe="family">
        <a href="#Royal Family"> The Family</a></li>
      <li style="display:inline-block;">
        <a href="#Population">Population</a></li>
      <li style="display:inline-block;">
        <a href="#Contact"> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm looking it to make it more presentable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css missing family class and in html you have classe instead of `class="family"`
Also `<div class="navebar">` should be `<div class="navbar">`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `display: flex;`

here is brief [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

you should use

```
flex-wrap: nowrap;
```

for the row to not be for two lines according your previous inline-block styling
and
`order: 1-3;`
for positioning elements from 1 that is far left to 3 that is all the way to the right

Start with assigning li **id** so you can do styling for each element
and then assign order 1, 2, 3 for them.

```css
.navebar{
  display: flex;
}
#family{
  order: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
#population{
  order: 2;
  width: 100%;
}
#contact{
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="navebar">

                <div id="family" >
                    <a href="#Royal Family"> The Family</a></div>
                <div id="population">
                    <a href="#Population">Population</a></div>
                <div id="contact">
                    <a href="#Contact"> Contact</a></div>

        </div>
```

Comment: thank you i corrected the navbar and edited it as class on the div but i did not understand well what you mean with your last paragraph

Comment: i also lost every modification with flex container :/

Answer (score 0):

The spelling of the class navbar in your HTML is wrong, you can change it to navbar from navebar and then for the css use padding: 0;

And for the links

```
 #royal  {   display: flex;   justify-content: flex-start; }

#population {   display: flex;   justify-content: center; }

#contact {   display: flex;   justify-content: flex-end; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="buttons">
                <li style="display:inline-block;" classe="family">
                    <a href="#Royal Family"> The Family</a></li>
                <li style="display:inline-block;">
                    <a href="#Population">Population</a></li>
                <li style="display:inline-block;">
                    <a href="#Contact"> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

i modified navbar but i can still not find a way to turn buttons as [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_color)